# Text Filter any List Column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, filter

When I add a text filter to a sharepoint page, it only gives me the option to connect the filter to a single column in a list webpart. How can I make the text filter operate like the OOB search bar that appears on a new library and search every column for the term? Do I have to create a parameter and select every column in a giant "or" statement?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Text Filter web part, we can only configure connection to get filter values from a column in another web part.

You can enable Search Box for the list web part by checking “Display search box” in Miscellaneous.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that limits search options to just one webpart and doesn't work on non-default views. I am using the text filter for three webparts on the same page.

Comment: No method to connect a Text Filter web part to multiple list web parts. You can link multiple lists as a data source using SharePoint Designer. Insert the data view with the combined data source into a SharePoint page. Then, use the build-in search in the data view for searching items in multiple lists.

Comment: I do not have a better solution, but for anyone visiting this question: you can get a parameter from the text filter and then filter every field in a list/library to that parameter in the view. Multiple webparts can use the parameter so every webpart on the page can be filtered by the same text filter.